# How to refresh materialized view in oracle

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

Iam trying to refresh the materialized view by using:

```
DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('v_materialized_foo_tbl')
```

But it's throwing invalid sql statement.

Then I have created a stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PROCEDURE MAT_VIEW_FOO_TBL 
IS
BEGIN
   DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('v_materialized_foo_tbl')
END MAT_VIEW_FOO_TBL IS;
```

This procedure has been created successfully but when i am calling this procedure with

```
MAT_VIEW_FOO_TBL;
```

it's throwing an error again.

Kindly suggest a solution for this issue.

Thanks,
Srinivas

Comment: are you using `exec DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('v_materialized_foo_tbl');` or `exec MAT_VIEW_FOO_TBL` or `BEGIN DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('v_materialized_foo_tbl'); END;`? Any of these should work.

Comment: I tried with exec MAT_VIEW_FOO_TBL; also     BEGIN DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('v_materialized_foo_tbl'); END; but didnt worked.

Comment: I think you are executing it from php as sql statement. It should be executed as procedure. I don't know php. How you call those statements. From Toad/SQLDeveloper or with php?

Comment: and... you should call it with 'V_MATERIALIZED_FOO_TBL' not lowercase.

Comment: Yes iam executing these statements from Zend Studio. And i tried with capital letter BEGIN     DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('V_MATERIALIZED_FOO_TBL'); END; where its giving new error                                                                   ORA-06550: line 1, column 59:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following:

   ; <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
The symbol "; was inserted before "" to continue.

Comment: can you elliminate the trailing `;`?

Comment: tried without ; but no success:(

Comment: post the relevant code from zend Studio and tag the question with php and zend...

Answer (score 58, accepted):

try this:

```
DBMS_SNAPSHOT.REFRESH( 'v_materialized_foo_tbl','f');
```

**first** parameter is name of `mat_view` and **second** defines type of `refresh`. **f** denotes fast refresh.
but keep this thing in mind it will **override** any any other refresh timing options.

Comment: This works fine in an IDE like SQL Developer, but if you are executing it from code (like ODP.NET etc..) then it has to be wrapped in BEGIN & END as @Waqas Ali suggests.

Comment: @TomHalladay Is there something wrong with using `EXECUTE` for that? (The raw function certainly didn't work from SQL Developer for me.)

Comment: Getting below error:

REFRESH FAST can not be used for materialized views

Answer (score 73):

Run this script to refresh data in materialized view:

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SNAPSHOT.REFRESH('Name here');
END;
```

Comment: Above code is tested various times, and it works fine, no exception/error. There may be some problem with your tool/mechane etc.

Comment: If you have a schema, use the following `dbms_snapshot.refresh('schema.view');`

Answer (score 18):

a bit late to the game, but I found a way to make the original syntax in this question work (I'm on Oracle 11g)

** first switch to schema of your MV **

```
EXECUTE DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH(LIST=>'MV_MY_VIEW');
```

alternatively you can add some options:

```
EXECUTE DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH(LIST=>'MV_MY_VIEW',PARALLELISM=>4);
```

this actually works for me, and adding parallelism option sped my execution about 2.5 times.

More info here: [How to Refresh a Materialized View in Parallel](http://www.doug.org/newsletter/march/mv_refresh_parallel.pdf)

Answer (score 8):

You can refresh a materialized view completely as follows:

```
EXECUTE  
DBMS_SNAPSHOT.REFRESH('Materialized_VIEW_OWNER_NAME.Materialized_VIEW_NAME','COMPLETE');
```

Answer (score 8):

Best option is to use the '?' argument for the method.  This way DBMS_MVIEW will choose the best way to refresh, so it'll do the fastest refresh it can for you. , and won't fail if you try something like method=>'f' when you actually need a complete refresh. :-)

from  the SQL*Plus prompt:

```
EXEC DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('my_schema.my_mview', method => '?');
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're working with SQL Developer, you have to put the dbms_view in lowercase.  The rest compiled fine for me although I haven't called the procedure from code yet.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "MAT_VIEW_FOO_TBL" AS 
BEGIN
  dbms_mview.refresh('v_materialized_foo_tbl');
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the below syntax:

Common Syntax:

```
begin
dbms_mview.refresh('mview_name');
end;
```

Example:

```
begin
dbms_mview.refresh('inv_trans');
end;
```

Hope the above helps.

Answer (score 1):

EXECUTE dbms_mview.refresh('view name','cf');

Answer (score -1):

When we have to use inbuilt procedures or packages we have to use "EXECUTE" command then it will work.

EX:

EXECUTE exec DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('v_materialized_foo_tbl');

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take some time to read how to write a good answer. read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7659/338114) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)