# How to refresh Materialized View using DB link in Oracle

Tags: oracle, distributed-computing, materialized-views

I have 3 schemas in Oracle. There's a Materialized View in the 3rd schema which I need to refresh from the 1st schema.

Below is the elaboration of the requirement:

`uv1` (1st schema) --> db link to `nwdb2` (2nd schema) --> `nwdb3` (3rd schema) --> `emp_de_mv` (MV)

I need to refresh the `emp_de_mv` from `uv1`.

I'm already executing a `SELECT`statement on MV from `uv1` as follows, which is working successfully:

```
SELECT * FROM nwdb3.emp_de_mv@nwdb2;
```

I tried refreshing the MV from `uv1` as follows as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554886/how-to-refresh-materialized-view-in-oracle).

```
EXEC DBMS_MVIEW.refresh('nwdb3.emp_de_mv@nwdb2', 'C');
```

But it's giving me following error:

```
Error starting at line : 25 in command -
EXEC DBMS_MVIEW.refresh('nwdb3.emp_de_mv@nwdb2', 'C')
Error report -
ORA-20000: ORA-00979: illegal reference to remote database
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 2809
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 3025
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 2994
ORA-06512: at line 1
20000. 00000 -  "%s"
*Cause:    The stored procedure 'raise_application_error'
           was called which causes this error to be generated.
*Action:   Correct the problem as described in the error message or contact
           the application administrator or DBA for more information.
```

Can anyone help me with above requirement?

Please note, I won't be able to create new DB link in `uv1` due to security reasons.

Comment: @APC Thanks for response. It worked. My problem is solved. But I'm still curious to know how am I able to access `nwdb3` from `nwdb2` directly, without DB link & why can't I access `nwdb2` directly from `uv1`, without DB link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `ORA-20000: ORA-00979: illegal reference to remote database`

You get this error message because, as [the documentation for `refresh()` states](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_mview.htm#ARPLS67203):

> "These materialized views can be located in different schemas and have different master tables or master materialized views. However, all of the listed materialized views must be in your local database."

The solution is to execute the refresh on the remote database, by invoking DBMS_MVIEW across the database link:

```
EXEC DBMS_MVIEW.refresh@nwdb2('nwdb3.emp_de_mv', 'C');
```

---

> how am I able to access nwdb3 from nwdb2 directly, without DB link & why can't I access nwdb2 directly from uv1, without DB link?

It's your environment so I don't - can't - know  the architecture. You describe `nwdb2` as a schema but also describe it as a database link. I'm guessing you have a database link called `nwdb2` which connects to a schema also called `nwdb2` that has privileges on another schema `nwdb3` in the remote database server. On the remote server `nwdb2` can reference objects in `nwdb3` schema without a database link because those schemas are local to each other. But `nwdb1` must use a database link because it is not local to either schema.